# Scipy curve_fit gives wrong answer

Tags: python, scipy, regression, curve-fitting, non-linear-regression

I have an oscillating data as shown in the below figure and want to fit a sine curve to it. However, my result is not correct.

The function that I want to fit to this curve is:

```
def radius (z,phi, a0, k0,):

    Z = z.reshape(z.shape[0],1)

    k = np.array([k0,])
    a = np.array([a0,])
    r0 = 110
    rs  = r0 + np.sum(a*np.sin(k*Z +phi), axis=1)
    return rs
```

a correct solution could look like this:

```
r_fit = radius(z, phi=np.pi/.8, a0=10,k0=0.017)
plt.plot(z, r,  label='data')
plt.plot(z,  r_fit, label='fitted curve')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

My result however from fitting the curve looks:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
popt, pcov = curve_fit(radius, xdata=z, ydata=r)

r_fit = radius(z, *popt)
plt.plot(z, r,  label='data')
plt.plot(z,  r_fit, label='fitted curve')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

My data is also as follow:

```
r = np.array([100.09061214, 100.17932773, 100.45526772, 102.27891728,
       113.12440802, 119.30644014, 119.86570527, 119.75184665,
       117.12160143, 101.55081608, 100.07280857, 100.12880236,
       100.39251753, 103.05404178, 117.15257288, 119.74048706,
       119.86955437, 119.37452005, 112.83384329, 101.0507198 ,
       100.05521567])

z = np.array([-407.90074345, -360.38004677, -312.99221012, -266.36934609,
       -224.36240585, -188.55933945, -155.21242348, -122.02778866,
        -87.84335638,  -47.0274899 ,    0.        ,   47.54559191,
         94.97469981,  141.33801462,  181.59490575,  215.77219256,
        248.95956379,  282.28027286,  318.16440024,  360.7246922 ,
        407.940799  ])
```

since my function simply represents a Fourier series, I also tried scipy.fftpack.fft(r) but I couldn't reproduce a close signal to that of which I have calculated the fft.

Comment: I get `name 'curve_fit' is not defined`. Could you add all imports that you do?

Comment: @peer: here: from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a graphical Python fitter with a sine equation and your data using the scipy.optimize Differential Evolution genetic algorithm module to determine initial parameter estimates for curve_fit's non-linear solver. That scipy module uses the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space requiring bounds within which to search. In this example those bounds are taken from the data maximum and minimum values.

[image: plot3]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings

r = numpy.array([100.09061214, 100.17932773, 100.45526772, 102.27891728,
       113.12440802, 119.30644014, 119.86570527, 119.75184665,
       117.12160143, 101.55081608, 100.07280857, 100.12880236,
       100.39251753, 103.05404178, 117.15257288, 119.74048706,
       119.86955437, 119.37452005, 112.83384329, 101.0507198 ,
       100.05521567])

z = numpy.array([-407.90074345, -360.38004677, -312.99221012, -266.36934609,
       -224.36240585, -188.55933945, -155.21242348, -122.02778866,
        -87.84335638,  -47.0274899 ,    0.        ,   47.54559191,
         94.97469981,  141.33801462,  181.59490575,  215.77219256,
        248.95956379,  282.28027286,  318.16440024,  360.7246922 ,
        407.940799  ])

 # rename data to match previous example code
xData = z
yData = r


def func (x, amplitude, center, width, offset): # equation sine[radians] + offset from zunzun.com
 return amplitude * numpy.sin(numpy.pi * (x - center) / width) + offset


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # min and max used for bounds
    maxX = max(xData)
    minX = min(xData)
    maxY = max(yData)
    minY = min(yData)

    diffY = maxY - minY
    diffX = maxX - minX

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([0.0, diffY]) # search bounds for amplitude
    parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX]) # search bounds for center
    parameterBounds.append([0.0, diffX]) # search bounds for width
    parameterBounds.append([minY, maxY]) # search bounds for offset

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# by default, differential_evolution completes by calling curve_fit() using parameter bounds
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# now call curve_fit without passing bounds from the genetic algorithm,
# just in case the best fit parameters are aoutside those bounds
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)
print('Fitted parameters:', fittedParameters)
print()

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print()
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: If I change the seed value and the function a bit differently, the result drastically changes. For example if the function is:  def func (x, a, phi, k, r0): 
    return r0 + a * np.sin(k * (x )  +phi)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that without providing an initial guess, the solution is not able to converge. Try adding a sensible initial guess:

```
p0 = [np.pi/.8, 10, 0.017]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(radius, xdata=z, ydata=r, p0=p0)
```

Note that if you were to use one of the other methods such as `trf` or `dogbox` then without the initial guess this would be more likely to return a RunTime error due to the parameters not being able to converge.

Comment: But if I want to have more sines like a Fourier series, it would be rather hard to have the initial guess for all the coefficients, and if I slightly go away from that initial point, it doesn't converge to the right solution.

Comment: @AlirezaRanjbar You may find that a single initial guess will work for multiple different sine waves. You can also try adding bounds to constrain the problem

Comment: @AlirezaRanjbar If you feel that this answers your original question, please accept and then as a new question based upon requiring multiple sine waves.

Comment: If no one else provided a better answer, I'll accept yours. I am hoping for something that is not sensitive to initial points, perhaps based on Fourier transforms

Comment: @NickMartin please see my answer using scipy's Differential Evolution genetic algorithm module to provide initial parameter estimates. This allows providing a *range* on values for the initial parameter estimates, which is usually much easier that providing individual fixed values.